# API Provisioning - Properties Account

Tags: google-apps-script

friends

I am administrator of my domain and I'm having a hard time getting to collect all the properties of accounts, using the provisioning api, as below.

```
function myFunction() {
  var base = "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/";
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_("provisioning", base);
  var url = base + "domain" + "/user/2.0"; 

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs).getContentText()
  var xml = Xml.parse(result);
  //Logger.log(result)
  var users = xml.feed.entry;

  var r = [['Usuário', 'Nome Completo', 'Permissão Administrador', 'Cota', 'Conta Bloqueada']];
  for( var i in users ) 
            r.push([users[i].login.userName,
            users[i].name.givenName+' '+users[i].name.familyName,
            users[i].login.admin,
            users[i].quota.limit,
            users[i].login.suspended]);
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  s.clearContents();
  s.getRange(1, 1, r.length, r[0].length).setValues(r);

}


function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

**Does anyone know tell the account properties, example quota used, date the suspension account.**

Comment: ?? I tested you code on my domain and it works as expected... do you still get errors ? Now because of you I have headers in portuguese ;-D

Comment: But I'll fix it, don't worry ;-))

Comment: Just one thing : it only gets 100 results. where do you give that parameter ? (now I'm not answering anymore but asking ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried UserManager service ? it's very easy to use and quite complete too... Well at least for my use it brings me what I need ;-)

here is how it works (simplified version, to get more parameters use the autocomplete on `users[i]`  ) :

```
function findUsers(s) {     
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getDataRange().clear()
  var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();
  var r = new Array();
//
  for( var i = 0 ; i < users.length ; i++ ){
    var Umail = users[i].getEmail(); 
    var UnomF = users[i].getFamilyName()
    var UnomP = users[i].getGivenName()
// here you can add other parameters
      if(users[i].getAgreedToTerms()){var Udejaconnect = 'oui'}else{var Udejaconnect = 'jamais'}
//
     r.push([UnomF,UnomP,Umail,Udejaconnect]);
  }   
  r.sort(function(x,y){
  var xp = x[0];
  var yp = y[0];
  Logger.log(xp+'   '+yp)
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;//  sort on name ascending
}
)
  var header = ['Nom de famille','Prénom','Email','Déjà Connecté?']
    sheet.getRange(1,1,1,r[0].length).setValues([header]).setFontWeight('bold')
    .setBackground('silver').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);
    sheet.getRange(2,1,r.length,r[0].length).setValues(r);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help ... my greatest need is to export quota has been used as e-mail for example, among other data .... Is it possible?

Comment: my need is to know the properties of the fields for user information. I located the site from Google api some things, but when I click on the Google site to access the properties of elemennto gives error page not found, as the link:  (https://developers.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference.html#google_apps_tag_apps:quota)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/  this one ? or this one : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reporting/?hl=fr

Comment: Serge,

is exactly this link (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reporting/?hl=fr) ... Do you have a sample report by this method? From what I saw, is a little harder to mount and when I returned unexpected error ...

Comment: following url with example code (https://docs.google.com/a/macros/sac.sulamerica.com.br/d/MolfJkGToVST8G_Z5pRmobcbyjXdBBQ8L/edit?uiv=2&tz=America/Sao_Paulo&docTitle=Planilha+sem+t%C3%ADtulo&csid=t-XtaC0emPRbaRxUsh42xIg.03158412421082600824.4417027047349740118&mid=ACjPJvHsmILUWJ8y3gpeI9XNobd4Bqyxm9gwfb0FnCCQw1a3uTjKA-a3lu5MnNgCPzgE4R6gIM46qHZFh3Ua9VSxLuGgLKfr-s-fICi3nQ&hl=pt_BR)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll be waiting and also try other things here.

Answer (score 0):

this is code that is returning unexpected error

```
function doGet()
{
  var domain = "sac.sulamerica.com.br";
  var date = "2012-06-24";
  var typeReport = "accounts"
  var XML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"+
            "<rest xmlns='google:accounts:rest:protocol'"+
            "xmlns:xsi=' http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance '>"+
            "<type>Report</type>"+
            "<domain>"+domain+"</domain>"+
            "<date>"+date+"</date>"+
            //"<page>1</page>"+
            "<reportType>daily</reportType>"+
            "<reportName>"+typeReport+"</reportName>"+
            "</rest>";



  var scope = 'https://www.google.com/hosted/services/v1.0/reports/ReportingData';
  var name = 'reporting';

  var OAuth = getOAuth(name, scope);

//  var headers = {        
//    oAuthServiceName:name, 
//    oAuthUseToken:"always",
//    headers: { "Content-type":"application/xml; charset=UTF-8"},
//    method:"POST",
//    payload:XML};

  OAuth.method = 'POST';
  OAuth.payload = XML;


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(scope, OAuth).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);
  var xml = Xml.parse(response);
  Logger.log(result)
  var users = xml.feed.entry;

  var r = [['Usuário', 'Email', 'Nome Completo', 'Permissão Administrador', 'Cota', 'Conta Bloqueada', 'Cota Usada']];
  for( var i in users ) 
            r.push([users[i].login.userName,
            users[i].login.userName+'@domain.com.br',        
            users[i].name.givenName+' '+users[i].name.familyName,
            users[i].login.admin,
            users[i].quota.limit,
            users[i].login.suspended,
            users[i].accounts.quotainmb]);
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  s.clearContents();
  s.getRange(1, 1, r.length, r[0].length).setValues(r);
}


function getOAuth(name,scope) // gets an auth certificate from Google
{
// Logger.log('--Get OAuth--');

 var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
 oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
 oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
 oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
 return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```